# Send a email via Excel

Tags: excel, vba, gmail

I have a project that i want to ditribute.
**I would like it to autosend me a mail on error.**

I tried here with CDO library, but i am not sure it is the best to use.

I have :

```
Private Sub MyErrorHandler()
    'Here i save the file to send it next
    Dim path As String: path = Environ("AppData") + "\Local"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs path & "AI_ErroringFile.xls"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Here i create my email
    Dim Cdo_Message As New CDO.Message

    Set Cdo_Message.Configuration = GetSMTPGmailServerConfig()
    With Cdo_Message
        .To = "myadress@yahoo.fr"
        .From = Environ("username") + "@ErrorHandler.com"
        .Subject = "Test"
        .TextBody = "Hello"
        .send
    End With

    Set Cdo_Message = Nothing
End Sub
```

and my gmail config function :

```
Function GetSMTPGmailServerConfig() As Object
Dim Cdo_Config As New CDO.Configuration
Dim Cdo_Fields As Object

Set Cdo_Fields = Cdo_Config.Fields
With Cdo_Fields
    .item(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort
    .item(cdoSMTPServer) = "smtp.gmail.com"
    .item(cdoSMTPServerPort) = 465
    .item(cdoSendUserName) = "AIErrorHandler@gmail.com"
    .item(cdoSendPassword) = "mypassword"
    .item(cdoSMTPAuthenticate) = cdoBasic
    .item(cdoSMTPUseSSL) = True
    .Update
End With
```

But on the `.send` instruction i have this error :
 `sendusing configuration value is invalid`

I have try the 3 possibles sendusing configurations without success.

**I am looking for a way to fix this or to send an email with vba without using outlook**

Comment: Try `Dim CDO_Message as Object // Set CDO_Message = CreateObject("CDO.Message")` ? (Follow [this page](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/send-emails-excel-vba/))

Comment: Same error with the ``` CreateObject("CDO.Message")```, and i am using quite the same config as writed on the page